# Observability: can we filter by tags then aggregate on prometheus or any metrics backend server

Tags: prometheus, metrics, distributed-tracing, opencensus

For example, I call Redis server with following command:

```
SET key "value"
```

After running, I want to track those 2 information at the same time:

- statistic of all write operators (so tag should be SET)
- statistic of all specific operators (so tag should be SET and key)

So I will create views for tracking metrics. There are 2 ways I can think:

- Single view with tag "SET" **and** key. and later hopefully I can filter by "SET" or by "SET" and by key. (1)
- Creating 2 views. First view only has tag "SET" and second view will have tags "SET" and key. So each view for each query. (2)

I prefer (1) because it is more elegant and I don't need to create too many views. My question is: If I do on (1), can it works on metric backend server ? (i.e: Prometheus). Or metric backend server doesn't support filter by tag and aggregation, so I must create separate views ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus enables you to browse metrics by a specific tag and aggregate them.

I recommend Prometheus documentation on [aggregation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) and on [tags](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels) (which in Prometheus are called 'labels').

If you are asking about 'views' in something like Grafana, then they are easily configurable and you can set the filtering with [variables](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/) for example.